# Why do certain activities seem to co-occur with well learnt skills?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, motivation

I have found that when I do certain activities, while engaged with them, I am inclined to do other activities, as well, which come naturally and do not seem to break productivity of the first ones, just on the contrary.

What do I mean - well, let me give these examples:

- when people do any sort of repetitive manual (motor) activity e.g. driving a car, cooking, dish-washing, etc they feel naturally inclined to talk with someone else or listen to music and these two kind of activities seem not to interfere with each other, just on the contrary, talking seems to make the manual work easier;
- when talking over the phone, many people naturally doodle on paper at the same time;
- in my student years I have found that while solving math problems I was inclined to draw things on paper (more specific things unlike the "random" doodling while on the phone);
- attending lectures couples quite well with daydreaming :)
- etc.

My questions is, is there any scientific formulation and/ or research over this observation of mine?

Comment: I see. It's been unanswered for quite some time. I might just dig into this and see if I can't come up with an acceptable answer for you.